# How to deploy my nodeJS application on wildfly server

Tags: node.js, express, wildfly

I have developed server Rest APIs using node and ExpressJS. Now I want to deploy this application on wildfly server so that my Client application can access the APIs.

What is way to achieve this? below is my app.js file.

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var routes = require("./routes/routes.js")(app);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log("Listening on port %s...", server.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try heroku cloud, it's simple and free untill some limits but it's nice for testing
[link](https://www.heroku.com/nodejs)

If you have vps you can:

1. Deploy code somewhere for example github
2. Connect to your serwer by ssh
3. Install node.js on server
4. Pull your api code from github
5. Install app dependencies (npm)
6. Run app